# Axios error 403: ERR_BAD_REQUEST using Spotify API for Javascript (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, spotify, http-status-code-403

I am currently making (attempting to make) a react app with the function of getting the users top tracks, but when I send the request, it returns

```
Request failed with status code 403
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
```

my code is

```
  const [tops, setTops] = useState([])

  async function topTracks(timerange, nsongs){
    const {data} = await axios.get(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks?time_range=${timerange}&limit=${nsongs}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    })
    console.log({data})
    setTops(data)
  }

//react part
{token ?
           <button onClick={() => {topTracks("short_term", 30)}}> get top songs</button>
                : <h2> please login </h2>
 }
```

Looking at other posts, my authorization flow may be incorrect but I'm not sure what I should change:

```
const CLIENT_ID = "++++++++++++++++++++++++++" 
  const REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:3000"
  const AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
  const RESPONSE_TYPE = "token"
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I had forgotten to pass the correct scopes for the search - I required "user-top-read" to make the query I wanted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).